# How can I check my solution for this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have $x''(t) - x(t) = e^{t}$ with boundary conditions $x(0) - x(1) = 0$ and $x'(0) - x'(1) = 0$.

I find the solution to be $x(t) = e^t \frac{4t-2}{8} + c_{1} e^{t} + c_{2}e^{-t}$, but finding $c_{1},c_{2}$ is tedious to find. I find $c_{1} = \frac{-\frac{1}{4} ((1-e) + e + 1)}{-(1-e^{-1}) - (1-e)} \cdot \frac{(1-e^{-1}) - \frac{e}{4} - \frac{1}{4}}{1-e}$ and $c_{2} = \frac{\frac{1}{4} ((1-e) + e + 1)}{-(1-e^{-1}) - (1-e)} $

How am I supposed to check if $c_{1},c_{2}$ are correct other than by computing by hand? This seems too messy, but I do not immediately see a mistake in my work.

Comment: It is of course best to compute by hand.  However, you can also try plugging in particular values of $t$.  If the equation holds on $t=0,1/2,1$ then it is **probably** correct.

Comment: Okay, thank you both for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

To solve:

$$\text{x}''\left(t\right)-\text{x}\left(t\right)=e^t$$

Use Laplace transform:

$$\text{s}^2\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{s}\text{x}\left(0\right)-\text{x}'\left(0\right)-\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{1}{\text{s}-1}$$

Solving $\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)$:

$$\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\frac{1}{\text{s}-1}+\text{s}\text{x}\left(0\right)+\text{x}'\left(0\right)}{\text{s}^2-1}$$

Now:

1. $$\text{x}\left(0\right)-\text{x}\left(1\right)=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{x}\left(0\right)=\text{x}\left(1\right)$$
2. $$\text{x}'\left(0\right)-\text{x}'\left(1\right)=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{x}'\left(0\right)=\text{x}'\left(1\right)$$

Using inverse Laplace transform:

$$\text{x}\left(t\right)=\frac{\cosh\left(t\right)\left(t+2\text{x}\left(0\right)\right)+\sinh\left(t\right)\left(t+2\text{x}'\left(0\right)-1\right)}{2}$$